# DirectWrite FPS SlowDown

Tags: windows-7, directx, frame-rate, direct2d, directwrite

After long time (like one month) I'm able to render text font on my application via interoperability trough Direct3D11, Direct3D10, Direct2D and DirectWrite. Now that I've found the solution, I've noticed that while drawing some text the FPS (frame rate per second) is drammatically slowered, any suggests?

EDIT:

Profiling the application the function that take me lot time is d2dRender->DrawText(...); where d2dRender is a ID2DRendertTarget pointer

Comment: performance profiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved drawing text only after a modification on it and drawing only the rendering texture, like:

```
if (myTextObject->IsChanged)
{
    d2dRenderTarget->DrawText(...); // and what else we need to draw on the surface
}

// Draw my Texture here (surface)
```

Comment: Alternately, if the text is unchanged between two frames, you can also cache the IDWriteTextLayout object (from CreateTextLayout) and call DrawTextLayout instead which avoids some relayout cost.